# VBA: How can I concatenate this

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

I'been doing a macro and when I have to print a bunch of info (strings and variables) in a cell it don't compile. How is the syntax then?

```
Sub TEST()
  
  Dim str1, str2 As String
  st1 = "Hi"
  st2 = "are"

  MsgBox (& str1& & "como" & str2 & "you")

End Sub
```

Comment: The ampersand is a concatenator. "me" & "you" results in "meyou". `& str1& & "como" on the other hand results in a compile error because there are more concatenators than strings. Each ampersand must be between two strings. No ampersand can follow another ampersand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code. Then you will be alerted if variables are undeclared.

You declare the variable `st1` as a variant, the variable `st2` as a string. (if you don't write the "as string" after every variable, it will not be a string.)

In the MsgBox, you use two different variables, `str1` and `str2`.

Such details matter.

And, of course, you have a few too many `&` signs in the MsgBox and not enough space characters.  Try

```
Option Explicit
Sub TEST()
  
  Dim st1 As String, st2 As String
  st1 = "Hi"
  st2 = "are"
  MsgBox (st1 & " como " & st2 & " you")
  

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, the **str** and **st** mistake was when I paste the code here. But thanks for the advice of "Option Explicit" and I realize that the "&" spaces also matters.

Answer (score 0):

First, suggest using Option Explicit as you use different variables to what you Dim (e.g. you declare "str1" but use "st1"). Next, str1 is declared as a variant, probably not what you intended. Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()
  
  Dim str1 As String
  Dim str2 As String
  
  str1 = "Hi"
  str2 = "are"

  MsgBox (str1 & "como" & str2 & "you")

End Sub
```

Comment: No spaces between words?

Comment: What did you add that I have not already written earlier?